# How do I make a video (.mp4/.avi) from a stream of images displayed in emgu cv's image box?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am trying to make a face recognition application with recording function. It will act like a cctv camera but with face recognition. I used emgu's imagebox to display the stream of images of my web camera. My problem is, how do I convert the stream of images to a video file and then save it to a local directory? 
Thank you very much.

I have tried some codes to download the imagebox frame. Unfortunately, I can only get it as an image file.

I used the following code to display the stream of images from my webcam:

```
Capture grabber; //declaration

// initialization

grabber = new Capture();
grabber.QueryFrame();
Application.Idle += new EventHandler(FrameGrabber);
```

I got the code for my face recognition here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239849/Multiple-face-detection-and-recognition-in-real

The expected output is a video file but the actual output I can only get is an image file.

Comment: Are you check VideoWriter libary for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used videowriter class.

code in my record button:

```
if(grabber == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            recording = true;
            int fps = Convert.ToInt32(grabber.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS));
            int foucc = CvInvoke.CV_FOURCC('X', 'V', 'I', 'D');
            int width = Convert.ToInt32(grabber.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH));
            int height = Convert.ToInt32(grabber.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
            writer = new VideoWriter(path+".avi", foucc, 10, 364, 293, true);
```

code in my stop record button:

```
        recording = false;
        if(writer != null)
        {
            writer.Dispose();
        }
```

code in my select directory button:

```
        SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
        if(save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path = save.FileName;
            btnRecord.Enabled = true;
            btnStop.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Another workaround i found is to use a screen recording library.